# Is using getState in Redux an anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm using Redux for the first time in a jQuery application and I have created small observable implementation. The observables are responding to changes on multiple properties of the state object, making changes to the DOM when state itself changes. If my observable callback needs 2 property values to accomplish its task, I will observe both values and then use those values to update the UI. The observables don't touch the state at all. They just present it to the observable in a callback so it can be used to update the UI with the state.

The project I'm working on is a refactor so I'm adding Redux after the fact. At times, I realize I need a specific state property in a piece of code that I may not have the time to properly refactor into an observable. In those instances, I call `getState` on the store to get what I need and move on with it. I can't help feeling like this approach is a little flawed.

Is using `store.getState` where ever I need it considered an anti-pattern? Are their explicit use-cases that I should avoid when using `store.getState`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `store.getState()` too liberally, you end up passing around the global state to random components. You run the risk of introducing coupling between components and parts of your state that have nothing to do with one another, which is anti-pattern. You should only call `getState` for two reasons: to fetch the initial state of the app, and in the update logic for your store -i.e inside your `store.subscribe()` callback.

As far as your observables go, in a typical component based view layer such as React, the only thing you really need to observe in a redux app is the entire application state *as a whole*, not individual pieces of it. Changes to the state as a whole are subscribed to and trickle down from the top level component.

However since you are refactoring a Jquery application I think your use of observables is acceptable. There is a library called [reselect](https://github.com/rackt/reselect) that you can use for this purpose if you don't feel like rolling your own. It helps you to compute state from arbitrary parts of the global state and provides efficient memoization so same inputs don't get recomputed.

> At times, I realize I need a specific state property in a piece of code that I may not have the time to properly refactor into an observable. In those instances, I call getState on the store to get what I need and move on with it. I can't help feeling like this approach is a little flawed.

One easy drop-in solution you could implement in cases like this is to use event emitters in your reducers to propagate pieces of the global state to the specific Jquery components that need them. This will keep you from having to pass around global state, preserving component isolation.

Comment: I'm using reducers to update my state in response to actions. The only reacting to state changes my observables do is update the DOM. Considering that this isn't a React app, how else would I know to update my UI if not with an observable?

Comment: Ok, I see your problem. There is nothing connecting the redux container state to your UI. In that case, I would probably use an event emitter to broadcast specific pieces of the state (when they change) to the jQuery components that need them -every time your reducers transform a piece of state, the components which have registered the event can makes the necessary changes to the DOM. You will avoid passing global state around and improve component isolation.

Comment: As far as your use of observables for computed state, I think that's fine. However, there is a library called [reselect](https://github.com/rackt/reselect) that's highly recommended for this kind of use-case and memoizes inputs.

Comment: My observables are the connection between Redux and the rest of my app and it sounds like I'm on the right path with he I use them. It's my use of store.getState outside of an observable that is problematic, which is what I expected. I've updated my question to try and clear up any confusion. If you want to update your answer to match up with our resulting discussion, I will gladly accept the it. Thanks!

Comment: updated the answer as per our discussion! Let me know if anything is not clear.