# Shouldn't Redux's .getState() return a copy of the state object?

Tags: javascript, redux

I am currently diving into Redux waters and ever since I understood how simple of a concept the reducers are I have to say I am really excited.

However, the question I pose on the title is something that struck me as odd.

Since immutability of the state object is such a core pillar of Redux, shouldn't the [`.getState()`](https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L73) method return a copy of the `currentState`, so that it is not exposed to the environment and thus impossible to mutate it?

Comment: Related: [Is using getState in Redux an anti-pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455996/is-using-getstate-in-redux-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: @raina77ow I don't think the two questions are very related

Comment: But they are, as it's impossible to understand why something functions one way or another without understanding how this 'something' is used. `getState` results are to be used only via getters and should not be modified; copying the whole object will be just a waste of time and cycles.

Comment: @raina77ow ok, that's kind of enlightening.

Comment: Also related: [Should you not return a copy of the state?](https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/1166).

Comment: @raina77ow That actually completely answers my question, thanks. Add it as an answer so that I can mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two reasons here: 1) in a proper Redux app, you never should attempt to mutate State directly, so `getState()` result is only to be used via getters, so there's no need to waste time and cycles on copying; 2) in fact, it's not that easy to copy it the right way. Quoting the related discussion from the [corresponding issue](https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/1166):

> You'd have to due a deep object assign to truely destroy all
>   references and we wouldn't want to do that, as you wouldn't be able to
>   compare if a particular part of your state tree changed, which is
>   incredibly useful in React via shouldComponentUpdate.

Still, one might decide it's beneficial to use an `Object.freeze()` over retrieved state as a safeguard (against mutating such an object somewhere else). However, passing the resulting state around too much is rarely a good pattern (as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455996/is-using-getstate-in-redux-an-anti-pattern)).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the store and the state it contains with the state of a Component.
They are two different concepts.
When you call the getState() you get the state of the "this" component; obviously you SHOULD NOT modify it; however you can modify it with a setState() and this triggers a repaint of the component.
Instead when you are within a reducer and an action results in a reducer changing state the returned state MUST always be a new object.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question. I am talking about the `.getState()` of **the** `store` object. The one you create with `redux.createStore()`